# Abstract classes and PyMongo; can't instantiate abstract class

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, pymongo, pymongo-2.x

I created the empty abstract class `AbstractStorage` and inherited the `Storage` class from it:

```
import abc
import pymongo as mongo

host = mongo.MongoClient()

print(host.alive()) # True

class AbstractStorage(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class Storage(AbstractStorage):
    dbh = host
    def __init__(self):
        print('__init__')

Storage()
```

I expected the output to be

```
True
__init__
```

however, the one I'm getting is

```
True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vaultah/run.py", line 16, in <module>
    Storage()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Storage with abstract methods dbh
```

The problem (apparently) goes away if I remove `metaclass=abc.ABCMeta` (so that `AbstractStorage` becomes an ordinary class) and/or if I set `dbh` to some other value.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't really a problem with ABCs, it's a problem with PyMongo.  There is an issue about it [here](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PYTHON-480).  It seems that pymongo overrides `__getattr__` to return some sort of database class.  This means that `host.__isabstractmethod__` returns a Database object, which is true in a boolean context.  This cause ABCMeta to believe that `host` is an abstract method:

```
>>> bool(host.__isabstractmethod__)
True
```

The workaround described in the issue report is to manually set `host.__isabstractmethod__ = False` on your object.  The last comment on the issue suggests a fix has been put in for pymongo 3.0.

Comment: Wow. Thank you :) Maybe I should write something like `if mongo.version_tuple < (3, 0): dbh.__isabstractmethod__ = False` in the class definition.

Comment: @vaultah: You could do that.  I don't think it will cause harm to set that attribute even in higher versions, though; it will just look a little weird.

Comment: Congrats on finding the actual bug report.  (In other news:  I type _way_ slower than I thought.)

Answer (score 1):

**Short Version**

`mongo.MongoClient` returns an object that appears to be (is?) an abstract method, which you then assign to the `dbh` field in `Storage`.  This makes `Storage` an abstract class, so instantiating it raises a `TypeError`.

Note that I don't have `pymongo`, so I can't tell you anything more about `MongoClient` than how it gets treated by `ABCMeta`.

**Long Version**

The `ABCMeta.__new__` method looks inside each field of the new class it's creating.  Any field that itself has a `True` (or "true-like")  `__isabstractmethod__` field is considered an abstract method.  If a class has *any* non-overridden abstract methods, the whole class is considered abstract, so any attempt to instantiate it is an error.

From an earlier version of the standard library's `abc.py`:

```python3
def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
    cls = super().__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
    # Compute set of abstract method names
    abstracts = {name
                 for name, value in namespace.items()
                 if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False)}
    # ...
    cls.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset(abstracts)
    # ...
```

This is not mentioned in the `abc.ABCMeta` class docs, but a bit lower, under the [`@abc.abstractmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) decorator:

> In order to correctly interoperate with the abstract base class machinery, the descriptor must identify itself as abstract using `__isabstractmethod__`.  In general, this attribute should be `True` if any of the methods used to compose the descriptor are abstract.

**Example**

I created a bogus "abstract-looking" class with an `__isabstractmethod__` attribute, and two supposedly-concrete subclasses of `AbstractStorage`.  You'll see that one produces the exact error you're getting:

```python3
#!/usr/bin/env python3


import abc
# I don't have pymongo, so I have to fake it.  See CounterfeitAbstractMethod.
#import pymongo as mongo


class CounterfeitAbstractMethod():
    """
    This class appears to be an abstract method to the abc.ABCMeta.__new__
    method.

    Normally, finding an abstract method in a class's namespace means
    that class is also abstract, so instantiating that class is an
    error.

    If a class derived from abc.ABCMeta has an instance of
    CounterfeitAbstractMethod as a value anywhere in its namespace
    dictionary, any attempt to instantiate that class will raise a
    TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class <classname> with
    abstract method <fieldname>.
    """
    __isabstractmethod__ = True


class AbstractStorage(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        Do-nothing initializer that prints the name of the (sub)class
        being initialized.
        """
        print(self.__class__.__name__ + ".__init__ executing.")
        return


class ConcreteStorage(AbstractStorage):
    """
    A concrete class that also _appears_ concrete to abc.ABCMeta.  This
    class can be instantiated normally.
    """
    whatever = "Anything that doesn't appear to be an abstract method will do."


class BogusStorage(AbstractStorage):
    """
    This is (supposedly) a concrete class, but its whatever field appears
    to be an abstract method, making this whole class abstract ---
    abc.ABCMeta will refuse to construct any this class.
    """
    #whatever = mongo.MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
    whatever = CounterfeitAbstractMethod()


def main():
    """
    Print details of the ConcreteStorage and BogusStorage classes.
    """
    for cls in ConcreteStorage, BogusStorage:
        print(cls.__name__ + ":")
        print("    whatever field: " + str(cls.whatever))
        print("    abstract methods: " + str(cls.__abstractmethods__))
        print("    Instantiating...")
        print("    ", end="")
        # KABOOM!  Instantiating BogusStorage will raise a TypeError,
        # because it appears to be an _abstract_ class.
        instance = cls()
        print("    instance: " + str(instance))
        print()
    return


if "__main__" == __name__:
    main()
```

Running this produces:

```
$ ./storage.py
ConcreteStorage:
    whatever field: Anything that doesn't appear to be an abstract method will do.
    abstract methods: frozenset()
    Instantiating...
    ConcreteStorage.__init__ executing.
    instance: <__main__.ConcreteStorage object at 0x253afd0>

BogusStorage:
    whatever field: <__main__.CounterfeitAbstractMethod object at 0x253ad50>
    abstract methods: frozenset({'whatever'})
    Instantiating...
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./storage.py", line 75, in <module>
    main()
  File "./storage.py", line 68, in main
    instance = cls()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BogusStorage with abstract methods whatever
```